# How document variable in JSDoc when it is an array containing objects?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have to following data structure:

```
this.subscribers = [
  {
    callback: () => {console.log( 'my callback'); },
    interval: 5,
    remaining: 3
  },
  {
    callback: () => {console.log( 'my callback 2'); },
    interval: 20,
    remaining: 1
  }
];
```

I have wrote the JSDoc like this:

```
/**
 * This variable store the array of callbacks to call repeatedly with the specified interval.
 * @property {function} callback  - The callback function the SchedulerService call.
 * @property {number}   interval  - The number of minutes between the runs.
 * @property {number}   remaining - The remaining minutes until the next call.
 * @type {Array}
 */
this.subscribers = [];
```

But with this jsdoc the `subscriptions` variable should look like this:

```
this.subscribers = [];
this.subscribers.callback = () => {};
this.subscribers.interval = 10;
this.subscribers.remaining = 2;
```

How does the proper [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/) comment looks like for this property?

Note: We are talking here about `@property` and not `@param`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{[].<TypeOfObject>}`

or

`{Array.<TypeOfObject>}`

I find it a little awkward, but you can see an example in the [docs](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html) for the row:

**Arrays and objects (type applications and record types)**

In your case, you would first define the `Subscriber` type:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Subscriber
 * @property {function} callback  - The callback function the SchedulerService call.
 * @property {number}   interval  - The number of minutes between the runs.
 * @property {number}   remaining - The remaining minutes until the next call.
 */
```

And then you would reference the type in your constructor (*whatever it is*) as such:

```
/**
 * This variable store the array of callbacks to call repeatedly with the specified interval.
 * @type {Array.<Subscriber>}
 */
this.subscribers = [];
```

Comment: Ohh, somehow I missed that page. Thanks for the answer, it seems a little bit over complicated to me tho.